# Editor de texto para respostas não permite certos tipos de caracteres multibyte

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Encontrei esse problema enquanto respndia a essa pergunta: [Por que deveriamos utilizar funções que começam por mb_?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78308/por-que-deveriamos-utilizar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-que-come%C3%A7am-por-mb/78725#78725)

Na resposta original, utilizei como exemplo, caracteres japoneses (precisei colar aqui como imagem porque não está permitindo os caracteres em formato texto):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para continuar a resposta, fui forçado a trocar o exemplo

```
echo strlen('I♥NY') . PHP_EOL . '<br />';
```

O importante é que na resposta daquela pergunta não influencia tanto, mas acho que isso é algum bug.

Quando tento digitar algum caracter japonês, aparece o tooltip na lateral:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionado: [“Comments can not contain that content”?](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/165/3)

Comment: Devido a spammer chineses, bloquearam os kanjis ?. entendo a medida, mas não me parece ser o meio mais correto. Há muitos ocidentais que vivem no Japão e Ásia em geral. No Japão, os brasileiros são a maior comunidade de ocidentais, atualmente 200 mil. Já tivemos picos de 380 mil. Também há outros latinos, americanos, europeus.. somando todos dá em torno de 500 mil. Do outro lado, no Brasil, são 2 milhões de japoneses, a maioria miscigenados, cerca de 80%.

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned [here](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/comments-can-not-contain-that-content), we put a block in place due to Chinese spammers acting across the network.

I took a look at the numbers, and this was only triggered twice since going up (so probably by the question OP here...).

So, I've removed it here.